# How do I setup placeholders in a string that can be replaced by interpolated values after selecting them from a dropdown?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, dropdown, placeholder

so I'm trying to use binding in Angular2 so that when someone selects a name from a dropdown menu at the top of my webapp then that name replaces specific placeholders throughout the form so it displays the person's name rather than "this person" or "your teammate". 
Not only do I want the name value of the object to be substituted into those placeholders, but I also want the email value to be pulled as well so that I can call on that from a mailing service when I press submit to send an email.

I've managed to get the binding working, so at the moment when I select the name it inserts it into the text, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make placeholders that can be replaced with the selected name. 
Also, how can I pull 2 values (name & email) from one ng-model?

an excerpt of my code:

```
<div id="toggle" class="row">>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-5'>
                <select [(ngModel)]="selectedTeammate.name">
                    <option *ngFor="let teammate of teammates" value= {{teammate.name}}>{{teammate.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  s

    <form>
        <div id="questions">
            <div id="question1" class="row"> 
                <div id="questionbox" class='col-md-10 col-md-offset-1'> 
                    <p>{{question1a}} {{ selectedTeammate.name }} {{question1b}} {{ selectedTeammate.name }} {{question1c}}</p>
                </div>
                <div id="textbox" class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
                    <textarea id="styled"  placeholder="Why or why not?"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="question2" class="row">
                <div id="questionbox" class='col-md-10 col-md-offset-1'>        
                    <p>{{question2a}} {{selectedTeammate.name }} {{question2b}}</p>
                </div>
                <div id="textbox" class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
                    <textarea id="styled" onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#e5fff3');" placeholder="Please provide a brief explanation"></textarea>
                </div>   
            </div>
```

What it looks like:

[The selected name is inserted into the string, but I need a placeholder to fill the gap in the sentence until a name is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rNr7.png)

If anyone can help me with my dropdown menu as well, then that would be absolutely fantastic! I've tried bootstrapping my dropdown to make it prettier, and even copied code from the bootstrap website to test, but the dropdown doesn't display any of the options when clicked. Here is the code I'm using for it.

```
<div class="dropdown row">
    <div id="dropdown column" col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
        <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" >Select a teammate youve worked with!
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[The dropdown displays correctly, but when clicked nothing happens and I don't see any of the list objects. I need this to work with ngFor just like the above dropdown does.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlZhp.png)

I'm also having issues trying to setup a favicon for the site.

I've included this in my  of my index file:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

and here is the file path of my favicon image:

C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Projects\sds-app\src\app\assets\Pictures\favicon.ico

I know this is a lot and maybe not formatted in the best manner, but let me know if there is any additional information you'd like. If you can help me with any of these questions I'd very much appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap select option you can show default show option as Select so you have to add one more line as option.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedTeammate.name">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option *ngFor="let teammate of teammates" value= {{teammate.name}}>{{teammate.name}}</option>
                </select>
```

So code will look like this.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful to know, but my biggest problem is that when I set up a dropdown menu with bootstrap it doesn't display the options and I can't figure out why. Do I need some sort of plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ngValue` you can pull the whole Object from your `[(ngModel)`. To set a "placeholder" for your Object, so that you have some value there in your view until replaced with your chosen teammate, you can initialize the `selectedTeammate` with some values, e.g:

```
selectedTeammate: Object = {id: null, name: 'your teammate', e-mail: ''};
```

And as mentioned, use `ngValue` to bind the whole object, and change the `ngModel` to be e.g `selectedTeammate` like I have used in these examples.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedTeammate">
    <option *ngFor="let teammate of teammates" [ngValue]="teammate">{{teammate.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Now when you have chosen a teammate, `selectedTeammate` consits of the whole object, not only the name. From there you can pull the e-mail related to that teammate.

Hope this helps! :)

[**Demo plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/lyjR1pR0AGe10Ot19Hne?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, with a little bit of tweaking this worked for me and I am now able to pull both the name and email property from the teammate object!